# Styling CalendarDatePicker

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar

I am trying to style CalendarDatePicker to a specific color palette. I have been able to style all portions of the CalendarDatePicker to the correct color palette except for the header.  All the websites and StackOverflow responses say this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Widget.Foo.CalendarDatePicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.Foo.CalendarDatePickerDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Buttons</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Buttons</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderLayout">@style/CustomHeaderLayout</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/android_purple</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/android_purple</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Buttons" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/android_purple</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomHeaderLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderLayout">
        <item name="android:background">@color/android_purple</item>
    </style>
```

however, the section:

```
<style name="CustomHeaderLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderLayout">
        <item name="android:background">@color/android_purple</item>
    </style>
```

is not setting the calendar header background purple, it is staying grey (see attached)[image]

Is there a different `item name` value that I should be using?

Answer (score 4):

To change the header background color you have to use the `<item name="colorAccent">`. Below are three different xml styles to customise the DatePickerDialog.

**Option 1 - @style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar**

```
<style name="MaterialCalendarCustomStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <!-- Buttons Color-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    <!--Days unselected Text Color and Month Text Color-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    <!--Header Background Color and selected Day Background Color-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    <!--Month Background Color-->
    <item name="colorSurface">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

**Option 2 - @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog**

```
<style name="DatePickerDialogAppCompatStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!--Header Background Color and selected Day Background Color-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    <!--Days unselected Text Color and Month Text Color-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    <!--Picker Background Color-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <!--Buttons Style (Text Color & backgroundTint)-->
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/MyButtonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonBarButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**Option 3 - @style/android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog**

```
<style name="DatePickerDialogMaterialStyle" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <!--Header Background Color and selected Day Background Color-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    <!--Days unselected Text Color and Month Text Color-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    <!--Picker Background Color-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <!--Buttons Style (Text Color & backgroundTint)-->
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/MyButtonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonBarButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And use any of the above styles programmatically like in the below example:

```
DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.MaterialCalendarCustomStyle, { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth -> }, 2021, 11, 20).show()
```

or in Xml Layout like below:

```
<DatePicker
    android:theme="@style/MaterialCalendarCustomStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

**Programmatically**

In case you want to change the header color programmatically make a subclass of `DatePickerDialog` and change the header background color like below:

```
class MyDatePickerDialog : DatePickerDialog {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    constructor(context: Context, themeResId: Int) : super(context, themeResId) {
        init(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, @Nullable listener: OnDateSetListener?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) : super(context, listener, year, month, dayOfMonth) {
        init(context)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, themeResId: Int, @Nullable listener: OnDateSetListener?, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) : super(context, themeResId, listener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {
        //find programmatically the android:id/date_picker_header View and change the Header Background Color
        val headerView: ViewGroup? = datePicker.findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/date_picker_header", "id", context.getPackageName()))
        headerView?.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_purple))
    }
}
```

and use the above subclass like below:

```
MyDatePickerDialog(this, R.style.MaterialCalendarCustomStyle, null, 2021, 11, 20 ).show()
```

**Result:**

[image: date_picker]

Comment: If you look at my post, I am setting colorAccent within the *Widget.Foo.CalendarDatePickerDialog* style.

In addition, I use that style when creating an instance of the CalendarPicker:

    return DatePickerDialog(
            requireContext(),
            R.style.Widget_Foo_CalendarDatePickerDialog,
            dateSetListener,
            year,
            month,
            day
        ).apply {
            setCancelable(false)
            datePicker.minDate = Date().time
        }

Comment: I have tested your xml style on two different devices, one with API 25 and one with API 30 and it works as expected, the header color is purple.
Do you have the latest version of Material Design com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0? And is your app parent Theme inherits from parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.. like eg: parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar”?

Comment: What android version are you using? I would suggest also to try to run this on a different device.

Comment: Yes, I am using com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0.  In terms of API, the min is 23 and the target is 30.  I have tried multiple emulators and two actual devices, a Pixel 6 and Galaxy S8.  The parent theme is Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar

Comment: @PerryHoekstra i have updated my answer with two more xml styles to test if it solve your issue. I have tested all the above xml styles and all of them give the same result.

Comment: I thank you for your effort but unfortunately, it did not change. I can change any color but that header.  To your point concerning the Theme, it is probably the parent theme of Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar but unfortunately, I cannot change it at this time.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @PerryHoekstra I have added also the programmatically way to change the header background color, check it out, i hope now you can change it in this way. If still not working i would suggest to create a clean project and check again any of the above solutions or you can upload a demo project on github with a minimal reproducable example of the issue so i can check it.